# How does this bezier curve rendering shader determine if a curve is concave or convex?

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I have read [an article about rendering quadratic splines on a GPU with a shader](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html).

The algorithm is explained like this:

- For each quadratic Bézier curve we use Bézier control points of the curve to create triangles. Triangles we get contain curves that are either convex or concave.
- Then we need to assign [u v] coordinates to the vertices of the triangles (article says that we assign values [0 0], [½ 0], and [1 1]; I'm not sure why these values are used).
- Then it say that instead of using [u v] coordinate to look up a color value as in texture mapping, we use the [u v] coordinate to evaluate a procedural texture. The pixel shader computes the expression `u^2 - v` using the *sign* of the result to determine pixel inclusion. For *convex curves*, a positive result means the pixel is outside the curve; otherwise it is inside. For *concave curves*, this test is reversed.

At the end of the article an example implementation of that algorithm is provided (reproduced below). It says it is a "quadratic curve pixel shader" so as I understand it, it should be able to render both *convex* and *concave* curves, but I am only able to get it to render convex curves.

Is it an incomplete example? If not, how / where it is specified if the curve is *convex* or *concave*?

```
float4 QuadraticPS(float2 p : TEXCOORD0, float4 color : COLOR0) : COLOR  
    {  
       // Gradients  
       float2 px = ddx(p);  
       float2 py = ddy(p);  
       // Chain rule  
       float fx = (2*p.x)*px.x - px.y;  
       float fy = (2*p.x)*py.x - py.y;  
       // Signed distance  
       float sd = (p.x*p.x - p.y)/sqrt(fx*fx + fy*fy);  
       // Linear alpha  
       float alpha = 0.5 - sd;  
       if (alpha > 1)       // Inside  
         color.a = 1;  
       else if (alpha < 0)  // Outside  
         clip(-1);  
       else                   
         // Near boundary  
         color.a = alpha;  
       return color;  
    }
```

PS: *Gradients* and *Chain rule* sections of the shader are about anti-aliasing I think.

Comment: Code is direct copy of Quadratic Curve Pixel Shader example provided in the article. I have implemented it in my test program and it is only rendering convex curves. I am unable to make it render concave curves without modifying the shader _(passing in another value for specifying the type and multiplying "sd" with -1 when curve is concave)_. Am I missing something or is this shader as is provided in this example only able to render convex curves?

Comment: ...because for concave curve formula should be changed from `p.x*p.x - p.y` to `p.y - p.x*p.x`. I am passing in [0, 0] [1/2, 0] [1, 1] as [u, v] texture coordinates for vertices of my test triangle and it seems to me mathematically impossible to pass in uv coordinates that would cause concave result. Unless I am wrong in some way.

Comment: Asking for help understanding some external resource isn't a question that's particularly well-suited to the site. If you were to ask a question such as "how, in general, can you determine this property of a curve" or reproduce a sufficient enough description of the resource that your question can be understood *without* following the link and reading the article, that would be better.

Comment: I have reworded the question. I hope its clearer now.

Comment: In case it's useful, here's a working version in GLSL, but all in a fragment shader.
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tj3Dy

This also shows a different way to render 2d quadratic bezier curves:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtS3Dy

And lastly, rendering 1d (explicit) Bezier curves is quite a bit easier than 2d if you are interested in seeing that a 1d cubic bezier curve rendered:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xd2Xz1